# How can I see output from docker-compose services when running interactive command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file like this:

```
my-service:
    ...

interactive-command:
    links:
        - my-service
    ...
```

I invoke it like this:

```
docker-compose -f path/to/docker-compose.yml run interactive-command
```

(Actually, I have two commands in the file that both link to the service, and sometimes I run one, sometimes the other, but I don't think this makes a difference to the question.)

The main problem is, I don't see any output from my-service.  In particular, I don't see error messages from it (although I can find them using "docker logs").  Furthermore, even if the service exits, the interactive-command keeps running, but it should exit with an error in this case.

If, on the other hand, I use "docker-compose up" instead of "docker-compose run", I get nicely formatted output from all services, but then I don't seem to be able to interact with the interactive command, even if I set "tty: true" and "stdin_open: true" for the interactive command.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Is the output you're looking for coming out of my-service?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker exec -ti <interactive container> bash` to get a shell on the interactive container.

Comment: I think you must have read my question too quickly and thought I was asking something else.

Comment: Hmm, maybe.  Exec gives you a way to interact with the container. There is no way to have both an Interactive container and the logs from other containers in the same terminal.

Comment: OK, I guess that answers my question.  It seems like an arbitrary restriction though.  In my case I have one container that runs a command to get an ip address and then sets up an ssh tunnel through it.  Another container runs a database client through the tunnel.  It would be nice for the user to see error messages if something goes wrong setting up the tunnel.

Comment: Also, it would be nice for the db client container to be stopped if the tunnel container is stopped.  I can't use `--abort-on-container-exit` for this because it only works with `up`, not with `run`.  I thought maybe there would be something I could put in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: There isn't any way to do that with Compose. You might be interested in [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/), which is a project that I've been working on. It allows you to configure project tasks that run in containers, and can launch a Compose project as well.  It will handle stopping and removing containers when the tasks finish. I think it may work for your use case.

Comment: "docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.  See 'docker exec --help'. Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...] [flags].   How does  `docker exec -ti <interactive container>` meet the two argument requirement?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the second argument.